# How to solve this linear algebraic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$\sqrt{2}R= \sqrt{R^2+ (xL-\frac{1}{xC})^2}$

I have been trying for quite some time to find $x,$ however I keep on solving it wrong.

I know there are two solutions, which are the following:

$x_1= - \frac{R}{2L}+ \sqrt{{( \frac{R}{2L})^2} +\frac{1}{LC} }$

$x_2= \frac{R}{2L}+ \sqrt{{( \frac{R}{2L})^2} +\frac{1}{LC} }$

Can someone please give me some pointers on how I could solve it.

Comment: Try squaring both sides of the equation. Then putting the terms with $R$ together and taking square roots, it becomes a quadratic equation in $x$, which should be elementary to solve.

Answer (score -1):

If you square both sides, multiply out the squared bracket, then multiply by $1/x^2C^2$ you get an equation in $x^2$ and $x^4$ which you can easily solve for $x^2$.